# maintain dialog data in firestore

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, nosql

I am looking for a way to store dialog data in Cloud Firestore. I am new to  NoSQL Databases, so any tip is appreciated.

My goal is the following:
I want a collection called "dialogs" which then stores the different dialogs in the following format (or similar)

```
dialogs:[
  {
    id:1,
    dialog: [
      {
        text: "hello is this a text?",
        turn: 0
      },
      {
        text: "yes this is a text",
        turn: 1
      }
    ],
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    dialog:[
      {
        text: "is this another text?",
        turn: 0
      },
      {
        text: "yes this is another text",
        turn: 1
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

My current approach in my web app looks like this:

```
db.collection("dialogs").add({id:1,dialog:[]})
```

First of all I would like to know if such a structure is possible (it does not exactly have to be this structure).

Second is it possible to generate a unique id and then query a particular id?

EDIT: I came up with this approach

```
const docRef = db.collection("dialogs").doc();
const dialog = {
  dialogId: docRef.id,
  intent: "SYMPTOM_INFORMATION",
  utterance: this.userInput,
  state: [],
  issuer: "USER",
  turn: 0
};
docRef.add(dialog)
```

What is now unclear for me is how I query **all documents** with **the same `dialogId`**

Comment: I suggest trying these things out for yourself first.  If you run into problems, please post the details of the situation that isn't working the way you expect.  What you're asking seems well within reason - go for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cloud Firestore allows you store multiple data types inside a document. You may want to check out the following [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#data_types). This will depend on your use case and needs but, for example, you can have your database structure looking something like this:

```
let data = {
  numberExample: 1,
  objectExample: {
    stringExample: "is this another text?",
    numberExample: 1
  }
};

let setDoc = db.collection('dialogs').doc('SET_YOUR_DOCUMENT_ID').set(data);
```

Note that when you use `set()` to create a document, you must specify an ID for the document to create. On the other hand, to auto-generate an ID for a given document, you must use the `add()` method, instead, as suggested in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#add_a_document).

**Edit1:**

To query all `dialog` documents inside a `dialogs` collection that meet the same `id` condition:

```
let dialogsRef = db.collection('dialogs');
let query = dialogsRef.where('id', '==', '1').get()
  .then(snapshot => {
    if (snapshot.empty) {
      console.log('No matching documents.');
      return;
    }  

    snapshot.forEach(doc => {
      console.log(doc.id, '=>', doc.data());
      // TODO: do something with the data.  
    });
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.log('Error getting documents', err);
  });
```

To query all `dialog` documents and their `id` field inside a `dialogs` collection:

```
let dialogsRef = db.collection('dialogs');
let allDialogs = dialogsRef.get()
  .then(snapshot => {
    snapshot.forEach(doc => {
      console.log(doc.id, '=>', doc.data());
      // TODO: do something with the data.   
    });
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.log('Error getting documents', err);
  });
```

More information can be found in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_multiple_documents_from_a_collection).

Comment: this does not exaclty help. It is basically the same as I did before. I am asking how to manage to connect different utterances to the same chat via an id.

Comment: I'm not sure I understood your question correctly, I thought you were asking about your database structure, whether it is possible to have an ID field and an object given a certain `dialog` document with its own unique ID. My answer explains some of the data types that you can use based on your question above and confirms that you can generate a unique ID for a document and query it later on. Now, taking a second look at your edited question, I realized that you may want to use an array `dialog` of objects, which will each contain `text` and `turn` properties.

Comment: To respond to your last question, you can use `where()` to query for all of the documents that meet a certain condition inside a collection, then use `get()` to retrieve the results. Check out the following [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_multiple_documents_from_a_collection) for a sample code.

Comment: ok maybe my question was not correctly formulated. My overall goal is that the user on a high level abstraction can select a certain dialog that can be edited. So for this I need to query all dialogs and extract its distinct dialog id. In my scenario this is not possible. And if a dialog is selected I want to append a new turn at the dialogs end. Maybe you can rewrite your answer based on this information

Comment: I updated my answer. I would recommend that you try this out firstly and then post any questions/concerns that you may have, as suggested by another user.